# The slash in the attribute `href` of tag <a/> RTE ckeditor - TYPO3 11

Tags: typo3, rte

there! i am faced with strange behavior ext:rte_ckeditor
when i add in editor this code...

```
<p><a href="/">link test</a></p>
```

and after save i get...

```
<p><a href="t3://folder?storage=0&amp;identifier=%2F">link test</a></p>
```

on front i get

```
<p><a>link test</a></p>
```

is it normal behavior for TYPO3 11 version and how can i change this behavior?

after click save i want to see...

```
<p><a href="/">link test</a></p>
```

is it normal behavior for TYPO3 11 version and how can i change this behavior?

Comment: It is normal behavior. Without any protocol, the URL seems to be an internal link. A such, TYPO3 tries to save it based on the pageUid - which cannot be determined in your case. The solution would be configuring the target-page (your "Home"?) to be available as `/`.

Comment: @JulianHofmann thank you for your replay... do you mean to set the target-page here.../www/config/sites/mysite/config.yaml ... "base: '/'" or where?

Comment: Normally, you will decide in RTEs link-wizard wether to link an internal page (and select one from page-tree) or link to an external page (and insert the full URI).  Why do you insert `<a href="/">` instead of selecting the wanted page? Absolute paths are dirty, manage content, not HTML. By linking to a pageID, TYPO3 will resolve the correct URL/path - also if the routing/slug of that page has changed. That is content management: connecting content.